# Find and replace TXT

Tags: find, text-editing

I've been using the [FART (Find And Replace Text)](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) tool
to modify files that I receive on a daily basis, there are over 4,000 txt files.

I need to modify one line in each one, but it includes numbers from 0000 to 9999 in two combinations

for example,

```
PM= 0001, 0865
```

How can I create a wild card to not include a line for each combination?
Or how can I do it with a BAT?
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always do it in Python (open each file in a loop and perform the search and replace on each one).

Comment: @MarijuanaTechnologyIT420 This is how it was before 
PM  = N.A., 0000, 1234
and this is how it should be
PM  = N.A.
It's just basically erase all that comes after the comma

Comment: As far as I know the F.A.R.T tool does not make use of wildcards like that but you can do something like `FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=," %A IN (file.txt) DO ECHO %A>>"newfile.txt"` instead.  This would mean you'd have to open `newfile.txt` to see the newly formatted data. With a little testing, you should be able to do this with each of the 4000 files in another loop, append `NEW` (or whatever you want) to the beginning of the file name, and then those files would contain the expected data. You could extend to rename or delete the old files and then remove the `NEW` file name prefix as well.

Comment: I'll be happy to add what I suggested in the above comment as an answer and further expand to include logic to process all txt files within a specific folder, and then do the rename and post process file cleanup, etc. too if you tag me back with an update after reading my comments to clarify how you want it to work. Also, please confirm that you understand how [Accepting An Answer](https://i.imgur.com/Kdn6Eyh.png) since I see you've only accepted one answer in the very few questions you've asked on the communities you belong. Hit me back and give me an update and I can further assist you.